# Math operations between fields with value and fields with null

Tags: influxdb

I have two fields in a series: `apples_count` and `oranges_count`.  And a tag: `market_id`.

The following query works beautifully if I have a value for `apples_count` and for `oranges_count`.

```sql
SELECT
    last("apples_count") + last("oranges_count") AS "total_fruit_count" 
FROM "fruits" 
WHERE "market_id"='1' 
GROUP BY time(1d)
FILL(null)
```

However, for certain `market_id`s, I might only have an `apples_count` (let's say `7`) and no `oranges_count` at all. I noticed that the `+` stops working and I only get `null` as a result. I would have expected to get `7` as a result.

Any suggestions on how to make this work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Fill(0) doesn't change your data - it just specifies the time grouping behavior.

So you still have your (hypothetical) "null" in your data point.

I, honestly, don't get what's the problem there. Would appreciate if you elaborate, if I didn't get it right.

P.S. Why hypothetical? Because you can't use this "null" explicitly (other than in fill()). You can't select with "null" in the conditions, you can't insert "null", etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited the question in hopes it is more clear now.

Comment: Then fill(0). Or, if, for instance, your counter is cumulative, not delta - you can opt for fill(previous)

Comment: Ok thanks! Could you maybe add this to your answer? So I can accept it :)